# ORACLE SQL create date from table colum parts

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I'm trying to create a select statement that returns  one row (date) combining  3 column entries

My idea that doesn't  work:

```
SELECT 
  TO_DATE( d_date.day_varchar   + 
           d_date.month_varchar +
           d_date.year_varchar  , 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
FROM d_date
```

Is this  possible in Oracle SQL and how can I get this result?

In SQL Server there  is  a `DATEFROMPARTS()` function but I don't know that  well Oracle specifics ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems fine.  You just need to update it for Oracle syntax:

```
select to_date(d_date.year_varchar || d_date.month_varchar || d_date.day_varchar, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

It is a curious that you would have a table with date parts, but not the actual dates.

Comment: Dimension table in my DW that has generated days, months, years

Comment: select to_date(d_date.year_varchar||'/'||d_date.month_varchar||'/'||d_date.day_varchar,'YYYY/MM/DD')date from d_date - this worked! tnx a lot!

Comment: @Therhinoman . . . The dimension table should have a date column.